# Angular2 Component test - Error: Can't resolve all parameters

Tags: angular, testing, mocking, jasmine

I'm working on testing one of my components for the first time using Karma/Jasmine etc and have been mostly following along with the [docs on testing](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#setup-files). My component requires 3 constructor arguments;

```
constructor(
  private myService: MyService,
  private renderer: Renderer,
  private element: ElementRef
) { }
```

I have attempted to *mock/stub* those dependencies based on [this section of the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#test-a-component-with-a-dependency) as follows;

```
// Mocks/Stubs
const myServiceStub = {};
class MockElementRef {}
class MockRenderer {}

// beforeEach block
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ MyComponent ],
    providers: [
      { provide: ElementRef, useClass: MockElementRef },
    { provide: Renderer, useClass: MockRenderer },
      { provide: MyService, useValue: myServiceStub},
    ]
  });

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
});
```

Despite this, whenever I run my tests I get the following error;

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MyComponent: (?, ?, ?).
    at SyntaxError.ZoneAwareError (test.ts:9250:33)
    at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (test.ts:44243:16)
    at new SyntaxError (test.ts:44453:16)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (test.ts:61503:31)
```

What am I missing here? Thank you!

Comment: You need to `TestBed.compileComponents`, which is asynchronous. See the section on testing components with templates.

Comment: It isn't that @jonrsharpe, the template is inline not in a separate file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be caused by circular DI, try to refactor your component MyComponent to inject service like this:

```
constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => MyComponentService)) private myService: MyComponentService) {}
```

Comment: This does appear to resolve the issue. What would be causing the circular DI though? The service is just a basic service with no injected dependencies that contains some abstracted business logic methods.

Comment: In general circular dependecy appears when you have 2 services that depends on each other. I had one app where i kept reference to component in service and had that issue.

Comment: or it wasn't reference, but i was dynamicly creating a component in service - dont remember exactly ;)

Comment: All of a sudden tests that had been passing, started not even running due to this error. Unfortunately I had not checked in for a while so could not pinpoint the change. I'd love to know why this works, but glad I found a way to continue.